# Does placing setVisible() function in the beginning of the function be different when I placed it at the end of that function?

Tags: java, jframe

I'm just new to Java GUI Programming and I'm having a problem that the components inside my panel is missing when I place the `setVisible()`function at the beginning of the function called by the constructor but it works fine when it is at the end. See code below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    new MainClass();
}

public MainClass()
{ 
    setFrame();
}

private void setFrame()
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    frame.setSize(400,400);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

   // Some area where the object of my components inside the panel is created and initialized.
   // If I just place a label and a button, it will appear on the panel. However if I add the JTextArea, all the components in my panel is gone. Just like the code below.

    textArea1 = new JTextArea(20,34);
    textArea1.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    textArea1.setLineWrap(true);
    JScrollPane scroll = 
            new JScrollPane(textArea1, 
                    JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, 
                    JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    panel.add(scroll);
    frame.add(panel);
    // Works fine when setVisible(true); it placed here.
}
```

What could the problem possibly be with regard to placing the `setVisible()` function to the beginning or to the end of the method.

Comment: When you tried did you notice any differences?

Comment: you should call setvisible at the end ,after adding all the elements

Comment: You should **not** call it from within the constructor at all!

Comment: @talex This question is the first step on the slippery path to "works for me"-bugs...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As already pointed out in the comments and the other answer:

**You should call `setVisible(true)` at the end, after all components have been added.**

---

This does not directly answer your question. The answer to your question is: **Yes, it makes a difference**. If you call `setVisible` before all compoents have been added, it *may* work, in some cases, with some programs, on some PCs, with some Java versions, with some operating systems - but you **always** have to expect that it may not work as expected in some cases.

You will find dozens of related questions here on stackoverflow and elsewhere. The usual symptoms of these problems are that some components are not displayed properly, and then suddenly appear when the window is resized. (Resizing a window basically triggers a layout and a repaint).

---

The likeliness of unexpected behavior is increased when you violate the threading rules of Swing. And, in some sense, you did violate the threading rules of Swing: You should always create the GUI on the Event Dispatch Thread!

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class SomeSwingGUI
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    // This method may (and will) only be called
    // on the Event Dispatch Thread
    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();

        // Add your components here        

        f.setVisible(true); // Do this last
    }
}
```

---

And by the way: Timothy Truckle pointed out in a comment that you should not invoke `setVisible` from the constructor. This is true. More importantly: You should usually *not* directly create a class that `extends JFrame`. (In some (rare!) cases, this is appropriate, but the general guideline should be to *not* extend `JFrame`)

Answer (score 2):

The components cannot be shown, because you add them after you call the setVisible() method of the Frame.

The Componet's **add()** method changes layout-related information, and invalidates the component hierarchy. If the container has already been displayed, the hierarchy must be validated thereafter in order to display the added component, as pointed [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add(java.awt.Component))
.

So in order to show the items, you should either call the revalidate() method of the frame or call setVisible() after all your components are added.

Unless there is no special need, you should call setVisible() after you have added every other component.

```
public class TestMain extends JFrame {

public static void main(String[] args) {
   JFrame test = new TestMain();
   //if the setVisible() is called too early, you have to revalidate
   test.revalidate();
}

public TestMain() { 
    setFrame();
}

private void setFrame() {
    setSize(400,400);
    setResizable(false);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    setVisible(true);
    JTextArea textArea1 = new JTextArea(25,15);
    textArea1.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    textArea1.setLineWrap(true);
    panel.add(textArea1);
    JScrollPane scroll = 
            new JScrollPane(panel, 
                    JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, 
                    JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    // this method invalidates the component hierarchy.
    getContentPane().add(scroll);

}
```

}