# how to repaint and or revalidate a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, listener

I learning Java right now and I try to make Memory game using Swing.

In the application I want to be able to resize the game board (which is a JPanel with a number of buttons). I try to achieve this with the use of a couple of JButton which all have the same custom Actionlistener. The Buttons work in the sense that they register clicking and successfully set my model dimensions. However I can not get my panel to redraw.

Is the code below enough to spot the problem?

**edit: I added more code after somebody asked.**

I pass the panel as an argument to my listener. I'm not sure if this is good practice in Java. Are there more elegant ways?

```java
public class MemoryApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                MemoryModel model = new MemoryModel();
                MemoryView view = new MemoryView(model);
                MemoryPanel panel = new MemoryPanel(model);
                new MemoryController(model, view, panel);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

```java
public class MemoryModel {
    private String faceText;
    private boolean faceUp;
    private int rows;
    private int cols;
    private int size;
    private ArrayList<String> cards;

    MemoryModel(){
        this.rows = 2;
        this.cols = 3;
        this.size = this.rows * this.cols;
        this.cards = new ArrayList<String>();
        generateCards(getSize());
    }

    private void generateCards(int s) {
        for (int i=0; i<s; i++) {this.cards.add("" + i);}   
    }

    public String getCard(int index) {return cards.get(index);}
    public int getSize() {return size;}

    public void setCols(int cols) {this.cols = cols;}
    public void setRows(int rows) {this.rows = rows;}
    public void setSize(int size) {this.size = size;}
}
```

```java
public class MemoryView extends JFrame{

    private MemoryPanel memoryPanel;
    private ToolBar toolBar;

    public MemoryView(MemoryModel model){
        super("title");
        // setup frame configuration
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(640, 320);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);

        // GUI elements
        memoryPanel = new MemoryPanel(model);
        toolBar = new ToolBar(model, memoryPanel);

        // layout
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        // add components
        add(toolBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(memoryPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}
```

```java
public class MemoryPanel extends JPanel{

    private ArrayList<JButton> memoryButtons;
    private CardListener cardListener;

    public MemoryPanel(MemoryModel model) {
        memoryButtons = new ArrayList<JButton>();
        cardListener = new CardListener(model);

        for (int i=0; i < model.getSize() ; i++) {
            JButton button = new JButton("text");
            memoryButtons.add(button);
            add(button);
        }

        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
        setLayout(new GridLayout(model.getRows() ,model.getCols()));
    }
}
```

```java
public class ToolBar extends JPanel{


    private JButton resizeSmall;
    private JButton resizeMedium;
    private ButtonListener buttonListener;

    public ToolBar(MemoryModel model, MemoryPanel memoryPanel) {
        buttonListener = new ButtonListener(model, memoryPanel);

        resizeSmall = new JButton("resizeSmall");
        resizeMedium = new JButton("resizeMedium");

        resizeSmall.setName("resizeSmall");
        resizeMedium.setName("resizeMedium");

        resizeSmall.addActionListener(buttonListener);
        resizeMedium.addActionListener(buttonListener);

        add(resizeSmall);
        add(resizeMedium);

        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
    }
}
```

```java
public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener{

    private MemoryModel model;
    private int rows;
    private int cols;
    private JButton button;
    private MemoryPanel panel;

    public ButtonListener(MemoryModel model, MemoryPanel memoryPanel) {
        this.model = model;
        this.panel = memoryPanel;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        button = ((JButton) e.getSource());
        switch(button.getName()) {
            case "resizeSmall":
                rows = 2;
                cols = 3;
                break;
            case "resizeMedium":
// etc
            case "resizeLarge":
// etc
        }
        model.setCols(cols);
        model.setRows(rows);
        model.setSize(rows*cols);
        panel.revalidate();
        panel.repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post [MRE] . (`ButtonListener` is posted but not used in the code. On the other hand `CardListener` is used but not posted)

Comment: excuse me. I added more classes. And removed the reference to CardListener since it is not relevant here.

Comment: The user clicks on one of the two `JButton`s _resizeSmall_ or _resizeMedium_ in your `ToolBar` which should change the dimensions of your grid and you want to place a separate `JButton` in every cell of your grid. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However I can not get my panel to redraw.

Yes, the panel will redraw when you invoke `repaint()` on the panel.

However, nothing changes because you haven't changed anything on the panel.

You create all the buttons and add them to the panel when you create an instance of the class.

> successfully set my model dimensions.

Yes but you never tell the panel that the dimensions have changed. And you have no logic in the panel to change anything when the memory model changes.

So in your `MemoryPanel` class what you need is a `reset(...)` method. This method would remove all the buttons and then recreate them based on the new values in the `MemoryModel`. Note this `reset()` method would also be invoked in your constructor when the `MemoryPanel` instance is created.

Comment: Thanx This helped. I added a ClearPanel() and ResetPanel() method. Also I added a ResetCards() method in my model to add extra cards.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in `MemoryView` class. You `setVisible(true);` and then:

```
// GUI elements
memoryPanel = new MemoryPanel(model);
toolBar = new ToolBar(model, memoryPanel);

// layout
setLayout(new BorderLayout());

// add components
add(toolBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
add(memoryPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

You should first add the components and prepare the layout and after that set the frame visible. For example:

```
frame.add(panel);
frame.add(anotherPanel);
//after adds, show the frame
frame.setVisible(true);
```

A good answer that mentions it is [Does placing setVisible() function in the beginning of the function be different when I placed it at the end of that function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40092281/does-placing-setvisible-function-in-the-beginning-of-the-function-be-different)

Comment: I followed your suggestion. But It did not change the functioning of the program. Just to be clear. I can draw the GUI and all it's components. It just doesn't redraw.

The link you posted suggested not extending JFrame. I changed this as well but that did not change anything either.